# Byte array percentage similarity

Tags: arrays, vb.net, byte, similarity

I am kinda new in VB.net; pretty much what I have been looking for is a way to calculate the similarity of a byte array. I have been able to determine whether they are equal or not, but I haven't figured out how to calculate how similar they are in percentage. Any idea is appreciated. Thanks! Leo.

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Do you mean you have two Byte arrays of the same length and you want to know what percentage of the elements in one array are equal to the the element at the same position in the other array? If so, you just need to loop through all the elements and count the ones that are equal, then divide by the number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function takes two Byte arrays as its arguments. If the arrays are not the same length, it throws an exception. Otherwise, it returns the fraction of the elements in one array that are equal to the element at the same position in the other array.

```
Function PercentAlike(array1() As Byte, array2() As Byte) As Double
    If array1.Length <> array2.Length Then Throw New ArgumentException("Arrays must have the same length")
    Dim same As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To array1.Length - 1
        If array1(i) = array2(i) Then same += 1
    Next
    Return same / array1.Length
End Function
```

[Added in response to the comment that the arrays may not be the same length]
If you need to calculate a percentage even if the arrays are of different lengths, you can use the following function. It returns the number of elements in one array that are equal to the element at the same position in the other array (ignoring the extra elements in the longer array) as a fraction of the number of elements in the longer array.

```
Function PercentAlike(array1() As Byte, array2() As Byte) As Double
    Dim same As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(array1.Length, array2.Length) - 1
        If array1(i) = array2(i) Then same += 1
    Next
    Return same / Math.Max(array1.Length, array2.Length)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Blackwood! However the the arrays will not be always the same length. I did not mention that. Any Ideas?

Comment: @LeonardoFernandez: Then you need to explain how the calculation is supposed to be done.

Comment: @LeonardoFernandez: I have edited my answer to show one way of handling arrays of different lengths. If you have something different in mind, please explain.